# No sound in games running on Wine

Tags: wine

I have **wine1.4-rc5** installed on my **Ubuntu 10.04**. I tried to play Call Of Duty 4: Modern Warfare and I got this error.

> Error During Initialization: Miles sound system initialization failed.
>   Make sure you have your sound card's latest drivers and DirectX
>   installed

I opened **Wine** configuration and opened the Audio tab.

The Output device is set to System Default. There isn't any drivers detected in Wine.
When I clicked **Test Sound** button, I can't hear the sound.
My Audio Driver is NVidia [HDA NVidia].
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why 1.4-rc5? Where is it installed from?

Comment: @Oli http://linux.softpedia.com/progDownload/Wine-Download-148.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got a unsupported version of Wine already and that doesn't seem to be working for you so I'd suggest another unsupported version from the ubuntu-wine PPA. The repo has taken to adding Pulseaudio patches for Wine so that the sound is much more reliable. It's the version I've been using for ages and it does Just Work™ 99% of the time.

Unfortunately for you the PPA doesn't support Lucid any more but you can grab the for-Oneiric packages directly from:

- http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu/pool/main/w/wine1.5/?C=N;O=D

If you're on a 32bit install you want the two files:

```
[ ] wine_1.5.13-0ubuntu1_i386.deb       14-Sep-2012 21:02   916
[ ] wine1.5_1.5.13-0ubuntu1_i386.deb    14-Sep-2012 21:02   1.0M
```

Or if you're on 64bit:

```
[ ] wine_1.5.13-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb      14-Sep-2012 21:02   918
[ ] wine1.5_1.5.13-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb   14-Sep-2012 21:02   1.1M
```

Obviously those filenames will change with time but the concept is you want a `wine_<full-version>.deb` and a `wine<major-version>_<full-version>.deb` file. The first depends on the second and is there to fulfil dependencies for other things that require `wine`.

Anyway, download what you need. Open a terminal, `cd` to where they downloaded and run `sudo dpkg -i wine*.deb` (assuming there are no other Wine debs lying around - delete them if there are).